# Headers in Knitr

Tags: r, yaml, knitr

Is there a way to use [knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/) from within the R console (*not* RStudio) to process a header. There are many examples using YAML headers such as:

```
---
title: "Habits"
author: John Doe
date: March 22, 2005
output: html_document
---
```

However, is there a way to have this header included using `knit2html` from within the R console? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `rmarkdown::render()`, which uses `knitr` on the inside (and knows about YAML headers and how to handle them)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm trying to avoid the additional dependency on pandoc (which is giving me errors). It's an alternative if I can get it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the YAML metadata is specific to R Markdown v2, i.e. the [**rmarkdown**](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/) package. The `knitr::knit2html()` function is for [R Markdown v1](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_migrating_from_v1.html) only.

Comment: I was honestly getting confused with the distinction between knitr and R Markdown. This clears up things a bit for me. :)